# What's the proper way to exclude uppercase word/s in regex python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Let's say I've scrapped this from a website.

PARIS - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua (2015). Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat 22/05/2015. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

- I can just use .replace ('PARIS - ','') and then get the texts with regex, but what if the place is changing in different article?
- How do I exclude the first "Paris" and " - " and get the other texts
- Should I seperate between the location and the content with regex?
- What should I think or do first when facing problem like this?

Here's my code to get the first string for my third question, assume that text is variable that contains these texts

`location = re.findall('^\w+', text)`

Comment: Please include the other text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what I meant by the other text is the lorem ipsum text, I'm sorry if it's confusing

Comment: why are you looking for uppercase ... if it always is `"<something> -"` why not just `s.split(" - ",1)[-1]`? why overcomplicate it with a regex when there is a much simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression that matches a sequence of uppercase letters and spaces followed by a hyphen at the beginning, and replaces it with an empty string.

```
text = re.sub(r'^[A-Z\s]+\s-\s*', '', text)
```